# Ubuntu 13.10: stuck at installing system step

Tags: 13.10, system-installation

I tried installing Ubuntu 13.10 x64 using USB on my Dell studio 1555, everything went fine until the final step. The installation process hangs once it reach the 'installing system' step.

Please advise your valuable suggestions.

Regards,

Comment: Have you tried more than once?

Comment: I cannot exactly say this is because of the flash drive but I've noticed this issue occasionally arise compared to an optical drive install. Are you sure you've downloaded & made a proper bootable USB by going through the guides?? Also, give it another go and see whether it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I thought I had the same problem.  I reached the 'Installing System' step, and then the progress bar did not move for a long time, maybe 20 minutes at least.  Then I left the screen and came back about an hour later, and it was displaying a 'Installation Complete' message.

So maybe try again, and leave it running at that step even if it looks frozen.